# What are current options to scan or convert a hand written note to a file on my laptop?

Tags: scanner, handwriting

I wonder how come there are not many options when it comes to scan or convert a device which could be connected to a laptop/desktop, which could -

1] Allow me to write with a digital pen on some special surface, which is connected to my laptop and thus converts my hand written notes to a pdf/jpg/word. (Microsoft's failed attempt at windows based tablet PC in past comes to mind, but not anymore)

Any such solution I can use with my laptop?

2] A document scanning device, apart from a flat bed scanner, integrated these days into multi function printers; anything that is portable enough to connect to my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [STAEDTLER digital pen](http://www.staedtler.com/digital_pen.Staedtler) could be interesting for you. I had a ACECAD Digimemo some time ago - it had similar use - output both digital and written on paper, but needed a special pad with batteries. Both devices do not need any computer to be connected during writing, only for data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe you are describing is usually called a  [Graphics Tablet](http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=296&name=Graphics-Tablets), or sometimes a "writing pad," or "writing tablet."
2. There are many forms of scanning devices.  Many [Document Scanners](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100008625&IsNodeId=1&name=Scanner%20-%20Document%20Scanners&SpeTabStoreType=1) are fairly small, and might do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this service called [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/about/download/). It can convert handwriting into text.